# how to set up netlify function on nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify, nuxtjs3, netlify-function

How to use netlify functions on nuxt 3?

in nuxt 2 just use this.$axios.post('....*netlify functions*) or in nuxt config (nuxt 2) only use generate for set payload to every page, but in nuxt 3 generate only set up routes as string not as object(routes & payload)